# Css: :nth-child: what am I missing?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 2 div which are like 2 `td's` in a table. Thus I want 2 divs red, then 2 divs blue and so on. This doesn't, work, what am I missing:

```
<style>
.irow :nth-child(4n+0), .irow :nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.irow :nth-child(4n+2), .irow :nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="irow">
    <div class="col-md-8">Inès va morfler grave</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Tête</div>
    <div class="col-md-8">Inès que des mots&nbsp;!</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Pompon</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nenad's answer seems to work. Also, there should not be a space before the `:` of your pseudo-selector.

Comment: Pseudo Selectors are sleectors that need to be attached to actual selectors. For example, the `:hover` state makes no sense without an element to hover on, and neither does the `:nth-child`. Either use `*:nth-child` if you don't care about what elements, or be more specific, but most certainly _attach_ it to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following CSS:

```
.irow div:nth-child(4n+1), .irow div:nth-child(4n+2){
  background-color: red;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+3), .irow div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is how it works:

`xn` selects every `x`th element, and the `+number` is the offset. For example `2n+1` will find every element this is a multiple of `2`, and select the one after it (`+1`). This would return the the element with the following indexes: `3, 5, 7, 9'.

In the code I posted above, the first rule selects every `4th` element (i.e. the `4th`, the `8th`). The second one selects every `4th` element `+1` (i.e. the `5th`, the `9th`), and so on for the other two

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftohu3ht/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/257/

```
.irow div:nth-child(4n+1),
.irow div:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+3),
.irow div:nth-child(4n+4){
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Aint (4n+4) equals to (4n) ? and why should I associate (4n) and (4n+3) instead of (4n) and (4n+1) ? This makes no sense (for my developper's point of view)

Comment: @NenadVracar You are wrong; `nth-child` starts from `n=0`.

Comment: @Kyle Oliveiro  not really. `.irow div:nth-child(4n+0)` targets `4th` element `.irow div:nth-child(4n+1)` targets `1st` element and so on...

Comment: @Kyle Oliveiro test it and see it for yourself.

Comment: @NenadVracar from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp: "Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, **n is a counter (starts at 0)**, and b is an offset value."

Comment: @Kyle Oliveiro that is all fine and dandy but https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/260/ :)

Comment: @NenadVracar That is because `4(0)+0 = 0`. If `n` starts from 1, then the first row in this example would not be blue: https://jsfiddle.net/k63d63ue/

Comment: Sorry but that is not true again, it would be blue https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/261/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96870/discussion-between-kyle-oliveiro-and-nenad-vracar).

Comment: **`n` in nth-child starts from 0.** Explanation here: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/262/